# Devide numbers on countup function

Tags: javascript, match

I'm starting to learn javascript and I basically needed a countup that adds an x value to a number(which is 0) every 1 second. I adapted a few codes I found on the web and came up with this:

```
var d=0;
var delay=1000;
var y=750;

function countup() {
document.getElementById('burgers').firstChild.nodeValue=y+d;
d+=y;
setTimeout(function(){countup()},delay);

}

if(window.addEventListener){
window.addEventListener('load',countup,false);
}
else { 
if(window.attachEvent){
window.attachEvent('onload',countup);

}
}
```

There's probably residual code there but it works as intended.

Now my next step was to divide the resultant string every 3 digits using a "," - basically 1050503 would become 1,050,503.

This is what I found and adapted from my research:

```
"number".match(/.{1,3}(?=(.{3})+(?!.))|.{1,3}$/g).join(",");
```

I just can't find a way to incorporate this code into the other. What should I use to replace the "number" part of this code?

The answer might be obvious but I've tried everything I knew without sucess.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your match statement, you need to convert your number to a String.

Let's say you have `1234567`.

```
var a = 1234567;
a = a + ""; //converts to string
alert(a.match(/.{1,3}(?=(.{3})+(?!.))|.{1,3}$/g).join(","));
```

If you wish, you can wrap this into a function:

```
function baz(a) {
    a = a + "";
    return a.match(/.{1,3}(?=(.{3})+(?!.))|.{1,3}$/g).join(",");
}
```

Usage is `baz(1234);` and will return a string for y our.

While I do commend you for using a pattern matching algorithm, this would probably be easier to, practically speaking, implement using a basic string parsing function, as it doesn't look anywhere as intimidating from just looking at the match statement.

```
function foo(bar) {
    charbar = (""+bar).split(""); //convert to a String
    output = "";
    for(x = 0; x < charbar.length; x++) { //work backwards from end of string
        i = charbar.length - 1 - x; //our index
        output = charbar[i] + output; //pre-pend the character to the output
        if(x%3 == 2 && i > 0) { //every 3rd, we stick in a comma, except if it is not the leftmost digit
            output = ',' + output;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Usage is basically `foo(1234);` which yields `1,234`.